# What is this ?: ?e php syntax?

Tags: php, sql, cs-cart

I'm trying to modify a SQL query in a php file but the best I can find in the source is:

```php
        $category_id = db_query("INSERT INTO ?:categories ?e", $_data);
        $_data['category_id'] = $category_id;
```

Does anyone recognise the ?:enityname ?e syntax and how I can find whatever :?categories?e defines?

Comment: Looks like some sort of placeholder. It's certainly not standard - you'll need to look at the code for `db_query`.

Comment: which db you are using

Comment: normally in sql is not allowed  the use of placeholder or  param for tableble or column name  too

Comment: I'm using mysql. the ?: and ?e are indeed placeholders. the ?e is filled by the $_data parameter. Just have to find how it is filled.

Comment: Since you've tagged it with cs-cart, I'd suggest grep'ing the entire cs-cart codebase for `db_query` to find the actual function definition.

Comment: maybe interesting? cs_cart manual: http://docs.cs-cart.com/4.3.x/developer_guide/core/db/placeholders.html

Comment: @RyanVincent thank you very much. I thought I went through all the documentation on the topic, but apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

CS-Cart's core DB concept is to use placeholders in SQL query (security).

You can read the [detailed documentation](http://docs.cs-cart.com/4.6.x/developer_guide/core/db/placeholders.html) section about this.